# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (13,) but got array with shape (3,)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am just creating a neural network for wine data by watching video from YouTube and I got error in model.fit

I am new to machine learning so i don't know any kind of solution so I haven't tried anything.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from google.colab import files

np.random.seed(3)

# Number of Wine Classes
classifications = 3

#load dataset
uploaded = files.upload() 


for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))

import io

dataset = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['wine.csv'].decode('utf-8')))

X = dataset[['Wine','Alcohol','Malic.acid','Ash','Acl','Mg','Phenols','Flavanoids','Nonflavanoid.phenols','Proanth','Color.int','Hue','OD','Proline']]

y = dataset[['Wine']]

# convert output values to one-hot
x_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train-1, classifications)
x_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test-1, classifications)

# creating model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(classifications, activation='softmax'))

# compile 
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=15, epochs=2500, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

The error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (13,) but got array with shape (3,)

Comment: where are you loading `x_train` and `y_train` from?

Comment: The input to your model declares that there should be 13 dimensions but it appears as though `x_train` has only 3??

Comment: you can check my code from this link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11YzIH-GKaGGN4BND9RuR9ZgypeKpA4NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you are one_hot encoding the input values, not the outputs

```
# convert output values to one-hot
x_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train-1, classifications)
x_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test-1, classifications)
```

It should be :

```
# convert output values to one-hot
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train-1, classifications)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test-1, classifications)
```

Then you need to save in X only the features and not the target so your new X is :

```
X = dataset[['Alcohol','Malic.acid','Ash','Acl','Mg','Phenols','Flavanoids','Nonflavanoid.phenols','Proanth','Color.int','Hue','OD','Proline']]
```

And last don't forget to change your variable in your fit method :

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=25, epochs=5000, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_15_input to have shape (13,) but got array with shape (3,)

Comment: Thanks for helping but still facing this problem i change the code as you suggest.

Comment: What is the shape of your X, y, X_train and y_train ?

Comment: wine data set check the code here  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11YzIH-GKaGGN4BND9RuR9ZgypeKpA4NO

Comment: Check again because it's works for me, i edited my answer because there is others problems

Comment: hope this works, never used colab ahah : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12khGrqJ3L_EJDC6Q9VbBCJhh2AoJb3Q1#scrollTo=LbV3yBCf4YOz

Comment: you can see my code again i change as you suggest but still got that problem https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11YzIH-GKaGGN4BND9RuR9ZgypeKpA4NO

Comment: You need to change model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=25, epochs=5000, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))  to model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=25, epochs=5000, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

Comment: Grant me access otherwise send me shareable link. And can you tell me what is best for coding because i am new in paython and machine learning.

Comment: With pleasure !  And for coding just do it where you are the most comfortable, i like jupyter and pycharm, but this is personal tastes ;)